# issue with buffer interface when tried to write to a file

Tags: python

TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

```
import os,stat

fd = os.open("foo.txt",os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
os.write(fd,"This is Test")
os.closerange(fd,fd)
print("Closed all the files successfully")
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface <-- This is the output that i get when tried to execute the program in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You need to write *bytes*, not Unicode strings:

```
os.write(fd, b"This is Test")
```

The `b'...'` is a `bytes` type literal. You could also encode a `str` type by using the `str.encode()` method:

```
os.write(fd, "This is Test".encode('ascii'))
```

Generally speaking, you want to use the [`io` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) rather than use `os.open()` and low-level file access. This is easily done by using the [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).